# How can I control the width of the X-axis labels on a horizontal bar RadChart?

Tags: telerik, radchart

What are the properties that control the width of the X-axis labels on a horizontal bar RadChart? Here's what it looks like now:

[image]

I need the labels on the left to be wider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually, just needed to keep the auto layout doing its thing, and disable auto wrapping this way:

```
var item = new ChartAxisItem();
item.Appearance.RotationAngle = AutoTextWrap.False
```